# Read permutation counts (counts transposition a and b) in the selection allows such Sort, heap

Tags: c#

As I wanted to check the times call allowed Swap in such sort SelectionSort, heapsort, Quicksort, Mergesort ...
Is how: I wrote the following apply to everyone for comments
 Quick sort

```
    public static void Quicksort(int []a,int l,int r)
    {
        if (l<r)
        {
            int q = Partition(a, l, r);
            Quicksort(a, l, q - 1);
            Quicksort(a, q + 1, r);
        }
    }
    public static int Partition(int[] a,int l,int r)
    {
        int Dem = 0;
        int Pivot = a[r];
        int i = l;
        for(int j=l;j<r;j++)
        {
            if(a[j]<= Pivot)
            {
                XL_SO_NGUYEN.Swap(ref a[j], ref a[i], ref Dem);
                i++;
                Dem++;
            }

        }
        a[r] = a[i];
        a[i] = Pivot;

        return i;
    }



    public static void Swap(ref int a,ref int b,ref int Count)
    {
        int temp =a;
        a=b;
        b=temp;
        Count++;
    }
```

how to print the number of times the call swap.
Count==???

Comment: What do you mean with print the Count?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you want...

```
public static int Partition(int[] a,int l,int r)
    {
        int Dem = 0;
        int Pivot = a[r];
        int i = l;
        for(int j=l;j<r;j++)
        {
            if(a[j]<= Pivot)
            {
                XL_SO_NGUYEN.Swap(ref a[j], ref a[i], ref Dem);
                i++;
                Dem++;
            }

        }
        a[r] = a[i];
        a[i] = Pivot;

        // Will write the Count to the output Window
        // To show "Output Window" ==> Menu - Debug - Windows - Output
        // Note that you increment Dem in swap and in this function, you sure?
        Console.WriteLine("Count: " + Dem);

        return i;
    }
```